# Google Calendar API - Reminders not sending emails for upcoming events

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

I have added code as per API documentation for setting reminders for email trigger before 10 min.

```
Event event = new Event();
...
...
..
// Set reminder for events



Event event = new Event();
EventReminder[] reminderOverrides = new EventReminder[] {
      new EventReminder().setMethod("email").setMinutes(10),/*
      new EventReminder().setMethod("popup").setMinutes(10),*/
  };
  Event.Reminders reminders = new Event.Reminders()
      .setUseDefault(false).setOverrides(Arrays.asList(reminderOverrides));
  event.setReminders(reminders);
```

But this is not sending any emails for any upcoming event. Not sure if there are any configuration changes required.

Comment: But it is working for manually created events?

Comment: Yes...it works for manually created event. The issue is when we create event at that time we are overriding the Reminders for event which does not work. Even i have tried to use default(true) but still no emails getting trigger.

Comment: If you inspect the automatically created Event via Google Calendar UI, is the reminder override visible there?

Comment: yes..i can see there the reminder has been set in response object

Comment: No, I mean, in Google Calendar UI, https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I'm overriding both email and popup. I also see the overrides in the return object, `useDefault` is set to `false` in it as well. However, I cannot see the reminders in the Google Calendar UI neither are the reminders pushed as expected. Did anyone find a solution, please?

Comment: If we inspect the automatically created Event, it shows data properly overridden as
"reminders": {
  "overrides": [{
   "method": "popup",
   "minutes": 5
  }, {
   "method": "email",
   "minutes": 10
  }],
  "useDefault": false
 }
But still the reminder emails are not getting trigger